# What is the best way to manipulate rows in subset of data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which has been grouped by a set of columns.

```
df.grouped<- df%>%
               group_by( A )
```

I now want to do some calculations on the values of column C (a number):

```
df.grouped[i, C_difference] <- df.grouped[ i, C] - df.grouped[ i-1 , C]
df.grouped[0, C_difference] <- NULL
```

Is there a way to do this in the piping, or do I do it by iterating over all values of A and B?

```
for( A in unique( df$A ) ){
  for( B in unique( df$B ) ){

    (execute code)

  }
}
```

**Example**

df

```
# A  B
# x  1
# x  3
# x  5
# y  7
# y  6
# x  2
```

Group by column A, order by column B
    df.grouped <- df%>%
                    group_by(A)%>%
                    arrange(B)

The result should be, if the data frame is shown ordered:

```
# A  B  C
# x  1  NA
# x  2  1
# x  3  1
# x  5  2
# y  6  NA
# y  7  1
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: You do it inside a `mutate` call (which you can add to the pipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr you should be able to do something like this.

```
df.grouped<- df %>%
             group_by( A, B ) %>%
             mutate(C_difference = C - lag(C))
```